# Is there a way to link a field of one table to a record of another table on Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently working on an Access model where I have 2 tables. One table would display chip IDs and the different processes it goes through, where the different process fields are yes/no checkboxes, and the other table shows the process IDs (where they are the same as the process fields of the other table) and the time taken for each process. I need to link the checked process fields for a particular chip ID to the time taken. Is there a way to link the fields to a record of the same name?

Comment: Table one is not a normalized data structure. No, the yes/no fields cannot 'link' to records of table two. Can use DLookup() in query but that really slows performance. Normalize.

Comment: @June7 If it's not possible, I'm alright with completely changing the data type but would there be an easier or better way to link the two tables together?

Comment: I already advised options. Either normalize table one or use DLookup(). DLookup() expression could be in query or textbox on form or report.

Comment: @June7 Alright, thanks!